# Change CSS Class when escape is pressed from full screen

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

I am using [this plugin](http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/66-jQuery-Fullscreen-Plugin.html) to make a flash video on my site go full screen. In order for the fullscreen to work properly, I am also using some javascript to add and remove a fullscreen class on the div when a user clicks a button to go in and out of fullscreen.

I am running into a slight problem with when users use the escape key to exit the fullscreen mode instead of the button. When the escape key is used, the fullscreen class does get removed which throws the layout out a bit. Is there a way to detect when the escape key is used to exit fullscreen and then remove the fullscreen class?

Also I am not much of a javascript coder, so a lot of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind event on document

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){ 

    if(e.which == 27){
          //add remove class.
     }
})
```

Comment: This worked, although I had to change addEventListener to bind. It was giving an uncaught error with addEventListener. b Thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 3):

Chrome will not fire a key event when exiting full screen mode. You need to define an event listener that listens for a change to full screen mode, like this (this stuff isn't well standardised, so you need to listen for the events fired by different browsers):

```
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', exitHandler, false);
    }
```

Then, when this event is fired by the browser, it will call an 'exitHandler' function that you define, and you can remove the class from your div when the user is *exiting* full screen mode by doing the following:

```
function exitHandler() {
    if (!document.webkitIsFullScreen && !document.mozFullScreen && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDivId");
        myDiv.classList.remove("fullscreen");
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is great and can easily be used for adding the class upon entering full-screen, and removing upon exit. Thanks!